# Updating value of cells in Excel with Java Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to update an existing Excel with Apache POI.

The thing is, I have an excel having in its 3rd column telephone numbers, and I want to correct them to the specific format using if-statements.

But I cannot write to the file.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 public void readingExcel(String fileName) throws Exception {
    try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName))) {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            int counter = 0;
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            int columnIndex = 2;
            row = CellUtil.getRow(counter, sheet);
            Cell cell = CellUtil.getCell(row, columnIndex);
            if (formatter.formatCellValue(cell).length() == 8)
                cell.setCellValue("+216" + formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
            if (formatter.formatCellValue(cell).length() == 11 && formatter.formatCellValue(cell).startsWith("216"))
                cell.setCellValue("+" + formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
            counter++;
        }

        FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
        workbook.write(outFile);
        outFile.close();
    }  
}
```

And I am getting this error

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0000000000000000, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:181)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:140)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:302)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:398)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:379)
at excelapp.myClass.readingExcel(myClass.java:50)
at excelapp.myClass.<init>(myClass.java:41)
at excelapp.ExcelApp.main(ExcelApp.java:26)
```

The thing is that it is really important for today, and I am getting really stuck on updating the values of that column :-/ anyone has an idea? I think I'm writing the wrong way..

Comment: Have you tried with another file? Can error come from the excel file, not from your code?

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? If not the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: do you have .xlsx file you want to work with? if yes you need `XSSFWorkbook` and `XSSFSheet` instead of `HSSF`. Aslo you should close the workbook after writing

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Best practice will be using the interfaces from `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` and `Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create...` as shown in [Busy Developers' Guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook). That will work with both, `XSSF` and `HSSF`.

Comment: @AxelRichter yea that might be but if he uses hssf for xlsx file, this might cause the error

Comment: I think the code is not right.. Im reading, but not writing how it should be done..

Comment: The error comes from that line: `HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);`. So it has nothing to do with writing but with reading the file.